# How to use an image as a button in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to make a login button as a single-file-component in Vue.js (it's a Rails app with a Vue.js front-end). If you click this button, it's supposed to take you to the an external provider's login page.

How can I use an image as a button? I'm guessing you use `v-on:click` for the actual redirect, but I'm stuck there.

Right now, this code below shows a hardcoded button that looks like `img(src="../assets/img/login_button.png")`. You can click on it, but that's obviously not what I want. I want to show the actual png image, not the path.

```
// LoginButton.vue

<template lang="pug">
#login-button
  <button v-on:click="redirect_to_login">img(src="../assets/img/login_button.png")</button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class LoginButton extends Vue{
  redirect_to_login():void{ // I haven't written this method yet 
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: kindly use this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903284/how-to-replace-button-with-an-icon-using-vue-js

Comment: I already had a look at that question, but I'm still confused. Still a Vue beginner here. Where am I supposed to put the `img(src="../assets/img/login_button.png")` then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't just use normal HTML image inside your button? I haven't used pug before.

```
<button v-on:click="redirect_to_login"><img src="../assets/img/login_button.png" /></button
```

Though since you're using Vue and not an actual HTML form you might not even need a button you could just add the click binding to the image instead

```
<img src="../assets/img/login_button.png" v-on:click="redirect_to_login" />
```

Comment: Thanks. We're just using pug for our project, so I don't really have a choice here. In the end, writing your solution in pug was like this: `img(src="../assets/img/btn_google_signin_dark_normal_web.png" v-on:click="redirect_to_login")`

Comment: Why would you use a framework like Vuetify and not use its components?  Defeats the purpose here does it not?

Comment: @JamieMarshall I don't think the OP mentioned Vuetify. I believe they were trying to make their own component using just Vue itself.

Comment: @kevmc, oops, my bad.  I ended up here searching for Vuetify question tags.  Not sure how I cross pollinated.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with pug, so I don't know what the correct syntax you'll need is. But you can use the `<router-link>` tag to set the route. For example (using Vuetify)

```html
    <router-link to="/">
      <v-img src="/path/to/img.gif"/>
    </router-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use:

```
 <a @click="Redirect">
     <img src='IMAGE_SRC'  />
  </a>
```

or

```
<img @click="Redirect" src='IMAGE_SRC'/>


new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            methods:
            {
               Redirect()
                  {
                     window.location.href = "https://jsfiddle.net/";

                     //or 

                      //this.$router.push('LINK_HERE'); // if ur using router
                  }
               }
      })
```

Demo LINK:

https://jsfiddle.net/snxohqa3/5/